# Property Change Logging

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, logging, properties

Currently on my application I am doing logging on any value the user changes, which works fine. I have a class object `MyObject` and `Logs` object and on each property I am raising an event as such:

```
private string _occupation;
[FieldAlias("_occupation")]
public string Occupation
{
    get { return _occupation; }
    set
    {
        if (this.Occupation != value)
        {
            string oldValue = Occupation;
            _occupation = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Occupation", oldValue, value);
        }
    }
}
```

The `MyObject` class also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and I have following event:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged<T>(string propertyName, T oldValue, T newValue)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new Helper.PropertyChangedExtendedEventArgs<T>(propertyName, oldValue, newValue));
    }

    this.Logs.Add(new Logs
    {
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
        CreatedBy = this.ModifiedBy,
        PropertyName = propertyName,
        NewValue = (newValue != null) ? newValue.ToString() : "",
        OldValue = (oldValue != null) ? oldValue.ToString() : ""

    });
}
```

Everything works fine except for he `CreatedBy` field above. As it is coming from `MyObject's` `ModifiedBy` property, the update doesn't happen immediately because at the time the field will contain previous user's name(hope it makes sense).

How can I reflect the changes as it happens, I cannot raise the event on `ModifiedBy` property as it is going to create a new row in `Logs` table, so is there any other options?

Comment: Maybe you can add your logging at the step where you actually change the Modified by. That is chain all changes to a list and log all changes when the modifedby propery change occurs. Either that or you would have to change the ModifiedBy property first

Comment: Where is `ModifiedBy` being set?

Comment: @Ginosaji it is set in MyObject as a property.

Comment: Users of `MyObject` are explicitly setting it after setting any property? If so, I'd move the logging outside this class as well by handling the `PropertyChanged` events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using the current user from cache this way it will update it properly.